# Pandas: how to edit values in a column of a .csv file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv file which looks as follows:[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buFdW.png)

I want to open this file using pandas and edit the column **Coordinate** by adding a constant value of 756 to each value in it. Finally, I want the changes to be reflected in the .csv file.

How do I do that?

Edit: What I had been doing is as follows (@EdChum):

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/TestBook1.csv')
df = df[['Coordinate','Speed']]

Coord = df['Coordinate']
Coord = Coord + 756
```

This is where I was going wrong. From here it would have been a messy affair to save changes into the .csv file.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, can you show your efforts as this is really trivial

Comment: @EdChum: Thanks for firing me up. I found my answer soon after you commented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also type:

```
df["Coordinate"] = df["Coordinate"] + 756
```

Comment: Thanks, you beat me.

Answer (score 3):

@EdChum: Thanks for your comment. It kind of fired me up. I was unnecessarily complicating things for myself. Following is what I did:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/TestBook1.csv')
df = df[['Coordinate','Speed']]

df['Coordinate']+=756
df.to_csv('C:/TestBook1.csv')
```

Initially I was loading all the values of the column into a variable and trying to find a way to save it. After your comment I thought of experimenting and I am glad that it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Define path where csv file is located

```
Location = r'C:\\'
df = pd.read_csv(Location,header=None)
df["Coorinate"].values +756
```

Do not forget to import pandas package

```
import pandas as pd
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that way as well.