# How to update the last column value in all the rows in csv file using python(pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to update last column value for all the rows in the csv file using Pandas. but while updating the value, other column value are dropping.

```
file = r'Test.csv'
# Read the file
df = pd.read_csv(file, error_bad_lines=False)
# df.at[3, "ingestion"] = '20'
df.set_value(1, "ingestion", '30')
df.to_csv("Test.csv", index=False, sep='|')
```

Comment: Perhaps you want [Pandas: how to edit values in a column of a .csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38719184/pandas-how-to-edit-values-in-a-column-of-a-csv-file)

Comment: I post my code there

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with `-1` for select last column and `:` for select all rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b

df.iloc[:, -1] = '20'
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E   F
0  a  4  7  1  5  20
1  b  5  8  3  3  20
2  c  4  9  5  6  20
3  d  5  4  7  9  20
4  e  5  2  1  2  20
5  f  4  3  0  4  20
```

EDIT:

For update all rows by last edit value swap `-1` with `:` and get last column value by [`DataFrame.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html):

```
df.iloc[-1, :] = df.iat[-1, -1]
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  b  b  b  b  b  b
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually, I am reading csv file and trying to update the last column value for all the rows.

Comment: @smviswa - So need `df.iloc[-1, :] = df.iat[-1, -1]` ?

Answer (score 0):

[`pd.DataFrame.set_value`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html) is not appropriate for setting all the values in a column. As per the docs, it is used to setting a scalar at a specific row and column label combination.

Moreover, since v0.21, it has been deprecated in favour of `.at` / `.iat` accessors.

Instead, you can set the value directly by extracting the final column label, assuming you have no duplicate column names:

```
df[df.columns[-1]] = '20'
```

Or, more directly, you can use the `iloc` accessor:

```
df.iloc[:, -1] = '20'
```